# Make linking to installed library, not dev library

Tags: makefile

I'm having a strange problem which I believe is related to a Makefile for a common open source project I am experimenting with. I am not a Makefile expert, I've only done the usual ./configure and make install.

Basically, I am adding some simple print statements to some source code which is compiled into a library. The print statements don't appear. I then try stepping into the library with a debugger, and it just 'skips' the entire section (it was compiled with -g -O0). This leads me to believe that when I run make, it is linking to the installed library on my system, instead of the recently compiled library in my dev src folder.

There is one line in the makefile that looks related:
prefix = /usr/local

Any easy changes I can make, or anyway to confirm my suspicions?

Comment: Update: Running Linux. ldd <executable> returns "Not a dynamic executable", so it looks like it is statically compiled. There is a libpoppler package installed on ubuntu, but I believe these would be dynamic libraries. Hmm..., not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Update2: I dropped the provided makefiles in favor of cmake generated ones. Everything seems fine now. I think it was just a case of over-complicated makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is linked dynamically, you can run `ldd` on whatever executable you are running to determine which is being selected. If it isn't what you expect, you can set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to override the search path for shared objects. And if it's linked statically, the path must be somewhere in the makefile. Use grep to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS, but on linux you should be able to figure out what exact file was loaded for a given library by checking /proc//maps. For instance if I want to know what file was used to provide libncurses.so for my shell, I could do:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/maps | grep ncurses
```

which gets me output like:

```
    7f25ab1e4000-7f25ab224000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6029412                    /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
    7f25ab224000-7f25ab423000 ---p 00040000 08:01 6029412                    /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
    7f25ab423000-7f25ab427000 r--p 0003f000 08:01 6029412                    /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
    7f25ab427000-7f25ab428000 rw-p 00043000 08:01 6029412                    /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
```

So now I know that ncurses.so was satisfied by /lib/libncurses.so.5.7

For your process, just replace '$$' by the PID of your running process. Other UNIX like operating systems will typically have a /proc like interface or a system tool that can give you this information about a running process. On Solaris for instance, the 'pldd' command can show you the equivalent of ldd output, but for any running process.